# Only Change Decimal's Scale

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've too many columns with *DECIMAL(A,B)*. Some of them have column default, some of them nullable, etc.

Instead of using:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN COLUMN_NAME DECIMAL(A,C)
```

Is there method that simply updates the SCALE of the DECIMAL?

Comment: As far as I know, no. You can, however, auto-generate your ALTER TABLE statements by querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (similar to the technique shown [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1184373-392-1.aspx)).

Comment: Ok, I can query and generate an sql query. But I have to generate different queries for nullables and columns that have defaults, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with modify keyword

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" MODIFY "column_name" "New Data Type";
```

Comment: "MODIFY" for Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)= ''

SET @sql = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ALTER COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' DECIMAL(A,C);'
            FROM   information_schema.columns
            WHERE  table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
                   AND data_type = 'DECIMAL'
                   AND NUMERIC_SCALE = --B
                    --add relevant filters
            FOR xml path(''))

--print @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Don't forget to replace `A` and `C` with proper `Precision` and `Scale`

Comment: Pretty sure your filter should be  `AND NUMERIC_PRECISION = A AND NUMERIC_SCALE = B` if you want to change all `DECIMAL(A,B)` fields into `DECIMAL(A,C)`.  I don't think there's a `SCALE` column in `INFORMAITON_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.  The detail doesn't mention it directly, but the question is about changing scale.

Comment: @BaconBits - Fixed the `scale` filter. Even there can be restriction in columns that needs to be altered, that's why I just mentioned relevant filters

Answer (score 0):

Use can achieve it by executing a dynamic SQL query. Use ***`stuff`*** function to concatenate each *`alter`* statement and retrieve the column names and other details from ***`information_schema.columns`***. Create an other variable to hold the new *`numeric_scale`* value and take *`numeric_precision`* from the ***`information_schema.columns`*** itself.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
declare @i as int = 3; -- change accordingly
select @sql = stuff((
        select 'alter table ' + [table_name] 
        + ' alter column ' + [column_name] + ' decimal(' 
        + cast([numeric_precision] as varchar(100)) + ',' + cast(@i as varchar(100)) + ');'
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'your_table_name'
        and data_type = 'decimal'
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 0, ''
);

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Actually I know how to iterate the "information_schema.columns" and generate the ALTER TABLE queries. But what you is actually is not correct. For example you should take nullables into consideration.

What I want is simply without effecting the default values of nullables, change scale to value C. Something like this:

ALTER TABLE 
CHANGE_COLUMN_SCALE C